# Getting User details using servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

I'm trying to retrieve the username of user who recently logged in. I used `.getRemoteUser()` method to read the username. But it was not displaying the user infromation.

my code is :

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
// Some introductory HTML...
String remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();
// See if the client is allowed
if(remoteUser == null) {
    out.println("Welcome");
} else {
    out.println("Welcome " + remoteUser + "!");
 }
```

I don't know why it was not giving the correct result. It always produces the result "Welcome". Which  means **request.getRemoteUser()==null**. Please anyone tell me how to retrieve the remote user information. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Recently logged in to what? How?

Comment: try request.getUserPrincipal().getName();

Comment: It depends upon authentication mechanism.

Comment: user who recently logged into the website.

Comment: Are you using any security mechanism or any license for login? If yes which security?

Comment: I'm trying to use j_security check...

Answer (score 1):

**request.getRemoteUser()** will return the user logged in else it will return null. It depends upon what kind of authentication you are using.

Another reason would be the client (browser) is not sending the user name with the request. That can happen if you are outside the URL tree that asked for the authentication

Answer (score 0):

use HTTP basic authentication only then you will have Remote User populated.

Here is simple tutorial on setting up a [basic HTTP authentication in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncck/index.html)

For a fact you can use any one of the below standard authentication mechanism

> static String    BASIC_AUTH
>             String identifier for Basic authentication.
>
> static String     CLIENT_CERT_AUTH
>             String identifier for Client Certificate authentication.
>
> static String     DIGEST_AUTH
>             String identifier for Digest authentication.
>
> static String     FORM_AUTH